# Zoom "Navigator" bar for ApexCharts

Tags: apexcharts

With ApexCharts I am able to zoom on the charts by marking an area of the chart with my mouse.

But I find it more user friendly with the "Navigator" by HighCharts, where you get a scrollbar with the chart in the bottom:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/navigator

Does anyone know if there is something similar in ApexCharts?

Comment: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/area-charts/github-style/
Here they have something like your screenshot, maybe that's usefull

Comment: Absolutely @ABR, looks perfect, thanks!